# How do I find consecutive repeating characters?

Tags: c, string

I'm working on a basic calculator (a personal project i've given to my self) and, at this moment, I'm working on verifying the given string.

My question is, how do I check for repeating consecutive characters?

My reasoning is that its simpler to just grab a string instead of parsing one character at a time; essentially creating more code and more work.

Since arithmetic is obviously a binary operation, it should be just that.

Instances such as,

- 5 +*/ 3 + 6
- 2 -- 5 + 2 ++ 8
- 6 *** 3 * 5
- 5 **/////---+++ 4

should all be considered to be invalid in this check.

White space should be ignored.

In essence, I need to stop repeating operators, but knowing a method to do this seems helpful in other programming goals as well.

There are similar questions to this one, but they are all in other languages and seem to be geared in achieving the inverse of this task.

To be quite frank, i just do not understand the basic underlying logic since I don't know the language that I'm reading (i.e. python, java, c#). I only know C so far.

The code that i have, so far, looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#ifndef _BASIC_CALC_
#   define _BASIC_CALC_

#   define STRLEN 81 //max string length
#   define MAX 41 //max strings to be allocated into memory
#   define SWIDTH 40 //limit asterick width

typedef _Bool bool;

const bool true = 1;
const bool false = 0;

typedef struct Count {
  int _of_store;
    int _of_tree;
    int _of_ops;
} count_t;

typedef struct Expression {
    char store[STRLEN];
    char ** tree;
    char ** ops;
    int total;
    count_t size;
} exp_t;

#endif

const char operator[] = { " */+-" };
const char digit[] = { " 0123456789" };

int isop(int operator)
{
    switch (operator)
    {
        case '*':
        case '/':
        case '+':
        case '-':
            puts("IS an operator.");
            break;
        default:
            puts("is NOT an operator.");
            return false;
    }

    return operator;
}

bool dblcheck(exp_t * expression, int position)
{
    //this function should search for consecutive operators
    //and should return false if is there are consecutive operators
    //or should return true if there are NO consecutive operators
    //the logic need not be inverted...
}

bool validated(exp_t * expression)
{   
    for (int index = 0; expression->store[index]; index++)
    {
        if (isalpha(expression->store[index]))
        {
            puts("invalidated: found alpha character!");
            return false;
        }

        if (ispunct(expression->store[index]))
        {
            if (!isop(expression->store[index]))
            {
                puts("invalidated: found bad operator!");
                return false;
            }

            if (!dblcheck(expression, index))
            {
                puts("invalidated: found consecutive operators!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool getexp(exp_t * expression)
{   
    printf("(expression)?> ");

    if (NULL == fgets(expression->store, STRLEN, stdin))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!validated(expression) && expression->store[0] != '\n')
    {
        puts("oops! you, the crazy person, provided an invalid expression.\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (expression->store[0] != '\n')
    {
        printf("your expression: ");
        puts(expression->store);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void stars(int count)
{
    for (int index = 0; index <= count; index++)
    {
        putchar('*');
    }

    putchar('\n');
}

void prompt(void)
{
    putchar('\n');
    stars(SWIDTH);
    puts("Type in a basic arithmetic expression.\n");
    puts("For example, 2 + 3");
    puts("or, 2 * 10 / 5");
    puts("are examples of basic expressions.\n");
    puts("Valid operators are +, -, *, and /.\n");
    puts("To quit, press [enter] on a new expression line.");
    puts("(expression)?> [enter]");
    stars(SWIDTH);
    putchar('\n');  
}

int main(void)
{
    exp_t expression;

    prompt();

    do {
        if (!getexp(&expression))
        {
            continue;
        }

    } while (expression.store != NULL && expression.store[0] != '\n');

    puts("Done!");

    return 0;
}
```

My intention was to have fun doing this, so it is as informal as it can possibly be. Hence, the certain insulting/sarcastic remarks.

As far as this posts `Tags` go

I wasn't sure what to use, so I opted to just use the `C` and `String` tags.

Thanks, in advance, to anyone who attempts to help me out.

Comment: Are you looking for a code review or help resolving an error?

Comment: neither. this code compiles and functions. i do not need a review. i could just post that on CodeReview otherwise. I'm just not sure where to begin with finding a repeating instance.

Comment: Remember the type of previous character when parsing the string. If previous was a number, next can be a number or an operator. If previous was an operator, next can only be a number.

Comment: You're trying to build a parser, which means you should be breaking the input up into tokens, and only after you've done that should you attempt to validate them. Since tokens may be composed of multiple characters, your approach of trying to validate the input character-by-character is inherently flawed. Tokenize first then validate. Also, keep in mind that repeating characters may be perfectly valid (eg, 2 - -5).

Comment: You are approaching the problem from a wrong end: [you need a parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), and you could either do it right away, or do it later, but there's no question that you would end up building one if you want to finish your project.

Comment: @WeatherVane The sequence `2 - -5` is a perfectly valid expression, which your logic would not handle. If the OP is going to disregard whitespace then he needs a set of precedence rules to determine if `2 - -5` means subtract -5 from 2 or it's an invalid set of operators.

Comment: @CareyGregory i have a token method set up already, which is why i used the struct expression type the way i did. the tree represents the expression->tree tokens; same with ops. and you guys bring up a good point. I forgot that (2) - (-5) is a valid expression.